# How do I declare the terminal type in vim so that :make can output colours?

Tags: vim, make

I use cmake, which produces makefiles with nice colourful output, but when I `:make` from Vim (well, actually MacVim, which is essentially GVim but I figure that doesn't make much difference), the output isn't coloured.

Is there a way I can declare the Vim terminal type as xterm-colour, or something, so that commands output colour control characters? (or does Vim not support this?)

Comment: The [Conque](http://code.google.com/p/conque/) plugin for Vim is a terminal emulator (for builds that include Python support; MacVim qualifies). You could use it to run *make* and have its output interpreted (though I have seen reports of flakiness in Conque’s terminal emulation), but you would lose some of the integration provided by [`:make`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/quickfix.txt.html#%3Amake_makeprg) (i.e. automatic quickfix parsing; though you could set up some automation to parse (part of) the resulting buffer with [`:cbuffer`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/quickfix.txt.html#%3Acbuffer)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The terminal used by gvim is a very dumb terminal. Among other things, it doesn't support ANSI color sequences. See

```
:help gui-shell
```

for a little on this. If you launch a shell from gvim (`:sh`), you can send ANSI color sequences to the "terminal" (e.g., `ls --color=always`) and you will see the escape sequences themselves, not colors.